# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES] - signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, sign

I've got 2 machines installing the same signed apk on two Android devices. One of the machines can't install and is getting **Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]** error message from adb. The second machine can install the app on different devices without any problems.

Interestingly, doing a jarsigner with -verify and -cert on the APK file gives different results on different machines. The one that cannot install the app is seeing all the JavaScript files as Text files:

```
     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.txt

     236 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/js/initOptions.txt

     229 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/js/main.txt

     233 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/js/messages.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.battery-status/www/battery.txt

     231 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/Camera.txt

     240 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/CameraConstants.txt

     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/CameraPopoverHandle.txt

     245 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.camera/www/CameraPopoverOptions.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/Contact.txt

     239 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactAddress.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactError.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactField.txt

     243 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactFindOptions.txt

     236 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactName.txt

     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/ContactOrganization.txt

     233 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.contacts/www/contacts.txt

     231 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/www/device.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-motion/www/Acceleration.txt

     238 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-motion/www/accelerometer.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-orientation/www/CompassError.txt

     239 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-orientation/www/CompassHeading.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device-orientation/www/compass.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/android/notification.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.txt

     239 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/DirectoryEntry.txt

     240 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/DirectoryReader.txt

     230 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/Entry.txt

     229 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/File.txt

     234 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileEntry.txt

     234 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileError.txt

     235 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileReader.txt

     235 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileSystem.txt

     242 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileUploadOptions.txt

     241 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileUploadResult.txt

     235 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileWriter.txt

     230 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/Flags.txt

     240 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/LocalFileSystem.txt

     233 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/Metadata.txt

     238 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/ProgressEvent.txt

     242 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/requestFileSystem.txt

     250 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/www/FileTransfer.txt

     242 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/www/FileTransferError.txt

     236 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/www/Coordinates.txt

     233 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/www/Position.txt

     238 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/www/PositionError.txt

     236 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/www/geolocation.txt

     243 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.globalization/www/GlobalizationError.txt

     238 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.globalization/www/globalization.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/InAppBrowser.txt

     230 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/www/Media.txt

     235 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/www/MediaError.txt

     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/CaptureAudioOptions.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/CaptureError.txt

     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/CaptureImageOptions.txt

     244 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/CaptureVideoOptions.txt

     234 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/MediaFile.txt

     238 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/MediaFileData.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.media-capture/www/capture.txt

     235 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/Connection.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/network.txt

     237 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen/www/splashscreen.txt

     234 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.vibration/www/vibration.txt

     233 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/checksum.txt

     232 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/cordova.txt

     240 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/cordova_plugins.txt

     229 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/wljq.txt

     234 Tue Mar 11 11:18:24 PDT 2014 assets/www/default/worklight/worklight.txt
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for suggestion! This is what was actually happening:

Because the APK is of a Hybrid application, it contained JS files. We transported the APK via email between the two machines. Apparently the Microsoft Exchange Server decides to check the insides of APK for 'dangerous' files and it did so, found a bunch of 'dangerous' JS files, removed all JS files and replacing them with helpful text files explaining it's actions. Therefore the APK would no longer install as it was tampered with by Microsoft Exchange. Obviously we didn't notice that at first as we didn't expect anything to be tampering with the APK.

Answer (score 0):

Hí vkislicins,

I had the very same issue, it was signed but refused to install giving me the exact same error.

first have a look at your present signature with
`$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs yourPackageName.apk`

if you get something like
`jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA-256 signature file digest for classes.dex`

**Try removing the META-INF folder from the apk and then sign again.**

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting a non-signed APK it is - as the name implies - not signed at all, not even with the debug key. The debug signed APK should reside in your project's `bin` folder!